# pad the list with zeroes if it has less than 3 entries

Tags: java, sql, checkbox

I have 5 checkboxes and I have limitted the selection to 3 only. The list values of each selected checkbox will be stored to the database and pad the list with zeroes if it has less than 3 entries. How can I pad the list with zeroes?

```
List < Integer > preferences = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
if (chckbxLei.isSelected()) {
    preferences.add(Integer.valueOf(chckbxLei.getName()));

}

if (chckbxAdv.isSelected()) {
    preferences.add(Integer.valueOf(chckbxAdv.getName()));
}
if (chckbxHis.isSelected()) {
    preferences.add(Integer.valueOf(chckbxHis.getName()));
}
if (chckbxOut.isSelected()) {
    preferences.add(Integer.valueOf(chckbxOut.getName()));
}
if (chckbxFAK.isSelected()) {
    preferences.add(Integer.valueOf(chckbxFAK.getName()));
}

if (preferences.size() > 3) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
        "Please Select Only 3! ");
    return;

}
Place place = new Place();
try {
    place.addPre(preferences);
} catch (Exception e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Place.java**

```
    public void addPre(List < Integer > preferences) throws Exception {
    DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
    Connection connect = db.getConnection();
    String sql = "Insert into preferences(Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ";
    PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        ps.setInt(i + 1, preferences.get(i));

    }
    ps.executeUpdate();
    connect.close();
    ps.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
   for(int i=preferences.size();i<3;i++)
       preferences.add(0);
```

Comment: this is sufficient: for(int i=preferences.size();i<3;i++)   preferences.add(0);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve then you have to create list with 5 elements with 0 values each. Then instead of adding values to the list you have to set value to exact element. Then you can iterate over 5 elements.

Comment: Ok. but then he will need to track how many values were actually inserted. .size() will not help.

Comment: Why is that? I understand it in that way: firstly he has [0,0,0,0,0] then he sets some values and have something like [0,2,5,0,1] (only three are set) so  finally he can iterate over 5 elements and set each of them as the parameter into his procedure. Maybe I misunderstood his question.

Comment: If user only select 2 checkboxes, it will be like [1,3,0,0,0]

Comment: No, only that he uses .size() to know that there were more than 3 options selected. This is just convenient to add only the selected values.